# Open a web page in a flex mobile app

Tags: android, apache-flex, mobile, web, adobe

I am developing a Flex mobile app, I use the navigateToURL function, It open the web page into the default web browser but I would like to open the web page into the application when I click on the button.

The full code of my app:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        title="Test">



<fx:Script>

    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.navigateToURL;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.media.StageWebView;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;
    import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent; 
        private var browser:StageWebView;
        protected function onViewCreated(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            browser = new StageWebView();
            browser.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 200);
            browser.stage = this.stage;
            browser.loadURL("http://stackoverflow.com");
        }       

        </fx:Script>



<s:Button x="209" y="67" label="test" click="event" />


 </s:View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html) class, it should fit to what you want to do.

Here is a sample code of how I'm using it:

```
    private var browser:StageWebView;
    protected function onViewCreated(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        browser = new StageWebView();
        browser.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 200);
        browser.stage = this.stage;
        browser.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onBrowserLoaded);
        browser.loadURL("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
```

In this case the browser is opened at the specified coordinates as soon as the view is created. But you could display it on the click event of your button, or trigger a pop-up or another view that will act as a container.

**EDIT**:
From what you've edited in your first post, you just have to fix the click handler so your code will be called when clicking the button. For the moment it's not.
Try the following:

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    title="Test">


<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.media.StageWebView;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
import mx.events.FlexEvent; 
    private var browser:StageWebView;
    protected function onButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        browser = new StageWebView();
        browser.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 200);
        browser.stage = this.stage;
        browser.loadURL("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }       

    ]]>
    </fx:Script>

<s:Button x="209" y="67" label="test" click="onButtonClicked(event)" />
```

**EDIT2**:
As you requested, you can use another function to close the browser. Assuming you want to do so when clicking a button, it would be something like this:

```
protected function onButton2Clicked(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    browser.dispose();
}
```

And the button declaration (contained in the Navigation button):

```
<s:actionContent>
    <s:Button label="Close Browser" click="onButton2Clicked(event)" />
</s:actionContent>
```

If you play around with the [actionContent Toolbar](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSa122979b46197256-7ee474a112a3e1a86b6-8000.html), you should find an interesting way to do what you're searching for.

Comment: Did you get any error? Was this code executed in a view or something else?

Comment: I get this error 
1046: Ce type est introuvable ou n'est pas une constante de compilation : FlexEvent.

Comment: I see, you should of course adapt the code I gave you. First that error means you didn't put an "import mx.events.FlexEvent;" at the beginning of your class.
Second, keep in mind that you may change the event type depending on how this function will be called (calling it from a button click will be a MouseEvent instead)

Comment: 1151: Conflit dans la définition browser dans l'espace de nom internal.

Comment: Do you have something else called "browser" in your code? Try renaming it.

Comment: I don't have something else called "browser"

Comment: I copy 2 time "private var browser:StageWebView;" There have more error with this but I have this error 
"1120: Accès à la propriété non définie onBrowserLoaded."

Comment: This one is because your didn't implement the onBrowserLoaded function, just remove the "browser.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onBrowserLoaded);" line since you don't need it for your first testing. Also feel free to learn the basics about events, this will help you a lot ! ;)

Comment: I remove "browser.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onBrowserLoaded);" line , but when i'm testing the app, I does not have action for the button

Comment: You should edit your question to post the full code of your app, this will be much more easier to troubleshoot everything at once ;)

Comment: @user3244813 I've edited my post to show you the modifications to apply.

Comment: it work !! But can I close this windows with a button in navigationContent ?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Do you now how can I make a refresh function for the browser ?

Comment: I would say browser.reload(); according to the [Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html), but I haven't tested it myself.

Comment: I had another view in my app, but when I open the windowed browser it does not close automatically

Comment: Do you now how close automatically the browser when I change of view

Comment: You have to call the same browser.dispose() as before, but this time in the function that will handle the view change.

Comment: I don't now how can I make this , in using an tabbedviewnavigator application

Comment: How can I make this for thé charge of view With à tabbedviewnavigator

Comment: It's not that I don't want to help you, but since the discussion is going far from the original question, you should create a new question asking your new objectives from where you are stuck at the moment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thinks it work well,

```
<s:navigationContent>
    <s:Button  click="onButtonCClicked(event)"  icon="@Embed('logo3/back3.png')"/>
</s:navigationContent>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[



import flash.net.URLRequest;
            import flash.net.navigateToURL;
            import flash.display.MovieClip;
            import flash.media.StageWebView;
            import flash.geom.Rectangle;
            import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
            import flash.ui.Keyboard;
            import flash.desktop.NativeApplication;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent; 
            import flash.display.MovieClip; 
            import flash.media.StageWebView; 
            import flash.geom.Rectangle; 

            private var browser:StageWebView;
            protected function onButtonClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                browser = new StageWebView();
                browser.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 70, 500, 400);
                browser.stage = this.stage;
                browser.loadURL("http://stackoverflow.com");
            }  

            protected function onButtonCClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                browser.dispose();
                navigator.pushView(menu)
            }   
            protected function onButtonRClicked(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                browser.reload();

            }  







        ]]>
</fx:Script>
<s:Button x="209" y="67" label="test" click="onButtonClicked(event)" />
```